# Disable Windows user's interactive login using C# service

Tags: c#, service, authentication, restrict

Is it possible to use a Windows service (C# - Local System priv.) to deny an interactive login?

What i want to achieve is when a user enters username and password, to be up to my service whether to allow him in or not.

Currently i do this by polling current interactive username every X seconds, and performing logout if needed. But i'd like to avoid this delay time because it allows user to login even for a few seconds. It would be more elegant to just deny logging in from the beginning.

Comment: Why don't you simply remove his user account in Windows?

Comment: I don't want to delete user's account, neither to hide it's icon from welcome screen. What i need is when the user tries to login, my service to check a time schedule and display a stop message if the user is out of allowed time.

Comment: That's a task solved by a Windows Domain, see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754934%28v=ws.11%29.aspx

Comment: Yes it is, but there is no domain.

Answer (score 0):

As you're in a Windows Service, you can register yourself to handle the `SERVICE_CONTROL_SESSIONCHANGE` event.
First, you must enable your service to handle this event :

```
public MyService()
{
    ...
    CanHandleSessionChangeEvent = true;
}
```

And then just override the `OnSessionChange` method :

```
protected override void OnSessionChange(SessionChangeDescription changeDescription)
{
    if (changeDescription.Reason == SessionChangeReason.SessionLogon)
    {
        // do work
    }
}
```

If you need more informations to do your work, I let you check the WTS API which will provide you dozens of informations (username is one of them) using the `changeDescription.SessionId` attribute (for example).